# Why did the aliens destroy the 'Welcome Wagon' helicopter?

Tags: independence-day

In Independence Day the aliens destroy the 'Welcome Wagon' helicopter. Why? They are about to take over the Earth and expect little or no resistance against their superior weapons. So why bother to destroy one insignificant aircraft. All it did was to forewarn the humans of their hostile intent.
I am not complaining. It was a fun flick.

Comment: Why? Why not? Just one less thing to destroy later

Comment: They didn't care: they believed they were essentially invulnerable.  They had technological superiority to the point where there was almost no conceivable way of stopping them. It was only possible to do so because of something they had overlooked, due to either their history being different enough to ours that they never experienced the idea of computer hacking, or because they evolved so far beyond it that they forgot about the idea (cf War of the Worlds, where a literal virus is humanity's saviour, and the Martians are described as having eliminated disease and then forgotten).

Comment: It was all a misunderstanding... What the Terrans thought was just non random pattern coincidentally translate in harsh word about the Alien's Mom.

Comment: Humanity approached the aliens with what they hoped would be seen as a universal message of peace. Perhaps the aliens just answered similarly with a universally recognisable message of violence. As to why they would flag their violent intentions - hard to say, we know nothing of their culture, perhaps engaging in a dialogue would be seen as a weakness, or perhaps similarly perhaps giving false hope would be seen as duplicitous - we don't know how their culture views such traits/actions.

Comment: One of the aliens on the bridge went "Lol, watch this you guys!" and blasted the puny human machine to smithereens.  The rest of them rofl'd all over the place.

Comment: @Tim I don't even think it was one of the ones on the bridge. The guys on the bridge just opened the door, an alien was wandering past, saw the helicopter and shot it through the door with its puny little laser. Then it just carried on walking, probably to the toilet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no canon mentioning of it at all for WHY. Thus we can only speculate.

What we CAN say is that DISTANCE was not the deciding factor for the aliens as the choppers stayed at the same distance during their messaging. So there are 2 main possibilities left:

- The flashing lights of the messaging device. These COULD have been interpreted as weapons as the aliens weapons are also very "light based" at least optically in the film (plasma weapons if I remember the novelisation correctly).
- A foreshadow for what is coming in order to raise panic and further reduce resistance.

Those two are just my own personal possible interpretations as like I said I'm sadly not aware of any canon reference that states the aliens mindset there.

Answer (score 0):

When President Whitmore tries to negotiate with the captured alien, we learn that they are massively xenophobic. So the aliens likely destroyed the helicopter out of disgust. This doesn't explain why they let the helicopter come that near (and even stay for a while), but it does explain why they care at all.

Answer (score -2):

Feathers or Lead? You're trying to ascribe human motives to *aliens*, this doesn't usually end well. If they were human I would suggest that knowing their own attack timeline there was no reason at that point for them to pretend immobility any longer than they already had. By the time anyone could react effectively to the destruction of the Welcome Wagon the alien attack plan would already be active so the aliens didn't have to tolerate a close human presence any longer.